# Installing Subpanel

Tags: electrical, hvac, subpanel, heat-pump

I am planning to install a subpanel to serve two heat pumps with a surge protector connected to the panel to protect both pumps, and I am hoping for confirmation that my plan is sound.

The main panel is flush mounted indoors on the wall immediately behind where the heat pumps will go. (I believe this satisfies the required clearance requirements as the meter will not protrude more than 6 inches beyond the panel.) My plan is to put a 100 or 125 amp subpanel on the other side of the wall behind and a few inches beneath the main panel/meter and then fish a wire through the wall and up into the panel. That way I should be able to fish a wire only a couple of inches and avoid opening up the drywall.

I'm planning to use #4 AWG copper (4-wire) and run the panel off a 60 amp breaker. As far as I've been able to determine, it's permissible to size the wire to the breaker rather than the panel. The mismatch between the panel and breaker size is because I want the breaker space of a large panel but I don't anticipate the panel ever supplying a greater load than 60 amp. The neutral and ground for the panel will not be bonded. The heat pumps each get a 15 amp 240 v breaker, and the surge protector also gets a double pole breaker.

Does anyone see any issues (code or otherwise) with this plan? Many thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: The only problem with just the right size of wire, is that it needs to be replaced if your requirements increase in the future.  4 gauge is the minimum needed for 60 amps.  Can go larger, depends on what size the breaker can fit, also depends on how easy the wire is to replace in the future if needed.

Comment: You can't run **wires** through the wall cavity. You can run cable or conduit through the wall cavity, and run wires through the conduit. Wires without conduit (or being part of a cable assembly) is not allowed (nor is it a good idea.) It's silly to stress about trivial drywall work in order to do a poor job of electrical work. In most cases exterior walls are not that trivial to fish through due to insulation. If using a cable, it needs to be properly clamped where it enters each panel.

Comment: Ecnerwal, the original panel is flush mounted so it is inset into the wall, depending on the wall it may only require a bushing , at worst a nipple.

Answer (score 4):

Using a bushing or nipple through the back of the panel into one on the outside is done by pros frequently.

I usually use 5-8 breaker position panels on a 50 amp panel so going bigger to #4 you can use the breaker that feeds the larger panel to size the wire.

You will need a NEMA 3R panel or one rated for outside.

Another thing you can do is get breaker locks that install on the breakers then as long as the units are within 50’ and in sight of the panel the lock outs fulfill the requirement for a locking disconnect (as long as the breaker is hvac rated)

Don’t forget you will need a 120v GFCI receptacle with a heavy duty or in-use cover.

Answer (score 1):

What Ed says, most pros would come straight out the back of one panel into another with a short (like 3" long) conduit.  Then bring individual wires through. This is handy in several ways.

Keep in mind that **the lugs you will be attaching to *are made of aluminum***.  However, "dissimilar metals" have shown to be of little concern; what kills connections is a) not torquing the lug to the specification with a torque wrench, and b) disregarding a terminal's rating.   *Were you planning to use a torque wrench?  If not, then that goes to show how "wives tales and superstitions" can misinform about actual safety.*

> As far as I've been able to determine, it's permissible to size the wire to the breaker rather than the panel. The mismatch between the panel and breaker size is because I want the breaker space of a large panel but I don't anticipate the panel ever supplying a greater load than 60 amp.

As the police *firmly* explained to me, having 130 mph tires does not mean I am required to drive 130 mph!

The 100A or 125A rating is just the same. It is the "redline"; higher amps than this *are unsafe*.  Obviously a 200A panel is better quality than a 100A panel, if one cares about such things.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Unfortunately I can't go straight out the back because the meter is directly behind the panel and my understanding is that running nonservice cable through the meter is prohibitive. So I've been planning to go out the bottom of the main panel and then into the back of the subpanel with SER cable. I can put the subpanel to the side of the main if necessary not to put an overly tight bend on the SER coming out of the main. 

And, yes, good point on the torque wrench. I do have one.